# Can't pull image with Docker

Tags: docker, dns

I'm running docker container on VM and it throws this error when trying to pull or build images:

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

I've tried the followings but none of them worked:

1. Add server names (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4) to /etc/resolv.conf
2. Edit /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf and add the following two lines:

```
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=208.123.76.34:8080"
Environment="NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1"
```

Reload daemon and restart docker

3. Remove docker completely and reinstall it

Can anyone suggest a fix fot this issue please?

Comment: Are you sure it's not `HTTP_PROXY=http://208.123.76.34:8080`? Not have http prefix?

Comment: Yeah, I've added that prefix as well but still did not work

Answer (score 0):

I've sorted this out by providing restarting daemon using the following commands:

```
sudo systemctl stop docker
sudo dockerd
```

Comment: What’s in the `daemon.json`?

Comment: Oh, it still did not work, I added the following line: 

```
{       
 "registry-mirrors":["https://registry.docker-cn.com","https://docker.mirrors.us>
}
```
and here is the output:

```
21c83c524219: Pulling fs layer 
9a80d14c35bd: Pulling fs layer 
0d32a27dde5a: Pulling fs layer 
21b66b94c49d: Waiting 
5673828eb75e: Waiting 
9497417a2507: Waiting 
26ef82a8f919: Waiting 
15d63e9e493f: Waiting 
48837d230e3d: Waiting 
Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

Comment: You should update your question with this information and delete this answer, then.